# How to convert a simple list into a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

How would you go about converting a list into a python data-frame.

For example:

```
listA = [1,20,12,4]
```

To be converted to

```
   listA
0  1
1  20
2  12
3  4
```

What is the simpliest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
listA = [1,20,12,4]
pd.DataFrame(data = listA , columns=['listA'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Very Helpful!